# hardcoded double variable with 0.3 value turns into 0.299999992

Tags: c#, double

In my computer when I harcode a variable with 0.3(or maybe some other value) of value and I debug and check the variable's value , its value is 0.29999992 but in my friends computer, it stays in 0.3.

```
 //stores 0.29999992
double variable= 0.3;
```

is there a configuration problem or something related?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is just an artifact of how binary floating-point works. There is no way of accurately representing `0.3` in a `double` (or a `float` for that matter). If you need that (e.g. for monetary applications), use `decimal` instead.

Comment: But we have to use a lot of Math.Pow that is not possible with decimals only with doubble , what is your advice?

Comment: Live with the fact that you don't have exact numbers. `0.3` in code, while not exactly `0.3` is still `0.3` if shown to 15 decimal places or so. You have plenty of precision for your calculation. Just be mindful of how much you show.

Comment: but why is 0.3 shown as 0.3 in my project and in my friends project as 0.22222229? is varies everytime?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of floating point numbers. Some, seemingly innocuous numbers cannot be represented exactly in floating point notation. A very close approximation is used instead.